# Cannot use external hard drive to reinstall Windows 7 by Windows 7 USB/DVD Download tool?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

Microsoft provides this  tool for making a usb installation drive. I was planning to use that to make a installation disk on a portable hard drive. (Ideally I should use a USB but I don't have one on hand right now.) However that tool says "no compatible usb drive found."

Is this impossible or did I missed anything?

(My portable hard drive is partitioned into 4 part, one of them is MS-DOS format.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tools work only with USB flash Drives, and fully formatted it before start to make boot-able windows Vista,7,8,2K8,2K8R2 or 2K12 Installer from DVD or Iso Image, So you cannot use your external hard disk with this tools.

Answer (score 0):

Set the partition as **active** using **Disk Management** (right-click the partition for the option) or **diskpart** (`list disk`, `select disk <number>`, `list partition`, `select partition <number>`, `active` in that order).

Then simply copy the contents of the DVD/ISO to that partition and try booting from the drive. Should work fine.